# Why can we change the differentials?(Brownian stochastic integrals)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Assume you have a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_t,P)$, assume that $B_t$ is a Brownian motion with respect to this filtered probability space.

Define

$$\text{sign}(x)=1, x \ge 0\\ \text{sign}(x)=-1, x <0.$$

It can then be shown that this stochastic integral is a Brownian motion with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$:

$$X_t=\int_0^t \text{sign}(B_s)dB_s.$$

Since $X_t$ is also a Brownian motion(this must be shown) we can calculate stochastic integrals with respect to it.

It is stated from various sources that we then have

$$dB_s = \text{sign}(B_s)dX_s.$$

**But how do we show this last equation?** What is it that allows us to move the $\text{sign}(B_s)$ over? It seems that they have the differential and have divided by $\text{sign}(B_s)$, and used that $1/ \text{sign}(B_s)=\text{sign}(B_s)$. But what allows us to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to just write out the right side of the equation.  By definition of $X$, $dX_s = \text{sign}(B_s)dB_s$, so $$\text{sign}(B_s)dX_s = \text{sign}(B_s)\text{sign}(B_s)dB_s = dB_s$$ because $\text{sign}(x)^2 = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But why are you allowed to do that operation with differentials? Is it a known rule? How is it proven?

Comment: Additionally (in case OP wants to look it up), the name of the property that allows us to do this is called "Associativity" of the Ito integral. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus#Properties